How can I undefine functions in PowerShell?
Consider a function definition, like:
function HelloWorld() { Write-Host "HellWorld!" }
I can undefine aliases using unalias, but I can't find an equivalent for functions.
How can I undefine functions?

Remove-Item Function:HelloWorld https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.4#description

I don't see an unalias command.

Functions can be removed using the Function: drive published by the PowerShell Function provider:
Remove-Item Function:HelloWorld


To complement lit's helpful answer:
A (perhaps obscure) alternative is to use namespace variable notation and assign $null:
$function:HelloWorld = $null


$function:HelloWorld returns the body of function HelloWorld as a script block.

You can change the body - or initially create the function - by either assigning a (new) script block or source code as a string (which is automatically converted to a script block); assigning $null, however, implicitly removes (undefines) the function.


